# Parametric to implicit form of a curve

Tags: parametric

"Find the implicit form of the curve defined by parametric equations $x = t+1,y=\frac{1}{t^{2}}$"

How can I clear $t$ to arrive at the implicit equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

If $x=\dfrac1{t+1}\iff t+1=\dfrac1x\iff t=\cdots$

If $x=t+1\iff t=x-1$

Put this value in $y=\dfrac1{t^2}$

---

Alternatively, $y=\dfrac1{t^2}\iff t^2=\dfrac1y\ \ \ \  (1)$

and $x=t+1\iff t=x-1\implies t^2=(x-1)^2\ \ \ \  (2)$

Compare the values of $t^2$ in $(1),(2)$ to eliminate $t$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the right value for x, edited!

Comment: @NicolásSiplis, It's even simpler! $t=x-1$

Comment: Wow, I just realized I was overcomplicating the solution by trying to clear $t$ from both $x$ and $y$. Thank you!

Comment: @NicolásSiplis, Please find the alternative method

Comment: I understand how you arrive at the result for both $x$ and $y$.
However, I'm not sure if there's anything else I should do to get the implicit form from: $f(x) = 1/(x-1)^2$.

I'm assuming all that's left is $1/(x-1)^2 - y = 0$, right?

Answer (score 4):

Another approach:

$$y=\frac1{t^2}=\frac1{(t+1)^2-(2t+1)}=\frac1{x^2-(2x-1)}=\frac1{(x-1)^2}$$

and we're done.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from
$$
x=t+1 \quad y=\frac{1}{t^2}
$$
we get 
$$
y = \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}
$$
and thus
$$
F(x,y) = \frac{1}{(x-1)^2} - y = 0
$$
as implicit curve equation.

Answer (score 2):

An approach: express $t$ as a function of the other variables.

$$t=x-1=\pm\frac1{\sqrt y}.$$

In this case, it is better to express $t^2$ to avoid the double signs:

$$t^2=(x-1)^2=\frac1y.$$

---

Alternatively, say: "take $t+1$, subtract $1$ to get $t$, square and take the inverse to get $\dfrac1{t^2}$."

Then $\dfrac1{(x-1)^2}=y$.